# Flutter - Ably - java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to io.ably.lib.types.Param

Tags: flutter, ably-realtime

This plugin ...

https://pub.dev/packages/ably_flutter

... asked me to do this ...

```
ably.ClientOptions options = ably.ClientOptions(
  clientId : '...',
  authUrl : '...',
  authHeaders : {'Authorization' : '...'},
);
ably.Realtime realtime = await ably.Realtime(options : options);
```

... before gave me this ...

> E/DartMessenger(12893): Uncaught exception in binary message listener
>
> E/DartMessenger(12893): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to io.ably.lib.types.Param[]

... and I don't know what else to do.

I thought it's because the backend responded wrong format data to Ably, so it was failed to convert it to `ably.tokenParams` type at app end. But backend guys told me there's nothing wrong at their end.

Greatly appreciate your help thank you.

Comment: Hi @stackunderflow . Thanks for raising this question. I am an SDK developer at Ably and wanted to let you know that it's a bug in our side. I have created an issue on Github if you wanted to track the status : https://github.com/ably/ably-flutter/issues/444

Comment: @ikbal thank you for your reply. it's great to hear from ably dev team themselves. actually i've find a workaround for this issue. i posted it as the answer for my question. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working either way using `authCallback` instead of `authUrl` and `clientId`, where `TokenRequest` or `TokenDetais` generated from data returned by back-end.

Authenticate with signed `TokenRequest`

```
ably.ClientOptions(
  key : token //Authentication token
  authCallback : (ably.TokenParams params) => ably.TokenRequest.fromMap(...)
);
```

Authenticate with Ably JWT

```
ably.ClientOptions(
  authCallback : (ably.TokenParams params) => ably.TokenDetails.fromMap(...)
);
```